# Call to undefined function views_embed_view() in php/php.module error

Tags: views, multi-sites, installation

I have a Drupal 7 based website that is multi-site. There is one sub domain ,say `sub.example.com` which is a Drupal installation with out any module or content type and the `example.com` it self and they both use the same core.

when I go to sub domain address this error

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function views_embed_view() in /home/A_NAME/public_html/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code on line 18**

is reported but the `example.com` works well. why while they both use the same core but different databases this error is reported?

Furthermore, I was trying to move a website from different server to this sub domain, so I only transferred the database of the old website to the sub domain database. from that time on this error is reported.

Comment: Probably because Views isn't enabled on the sub domain version of Drupal

Comment: @Clive I guess you are right, the views function is used but the `views` module files are not moved in modules folder.